# Netbeans start xdebug on specific page

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-8

I have been programming PHP for quite some time but have never used an IDE or debugger to assist with this process. I decided to try and learn Netbeans with XDebug for PHP code assistance. Setting things up in the ini files was easy enough and I can verify that it is working. However, when I start the debugger in Netbeans it loads the index page of my site and the page I actually want to debug is 5 pages deep and can take a long time to navigate to with the debugger on.

I have installed the Xdebug helper for Chrome but the debugger gets suspended in Netbeans and never debugs anything on the page. Here are the steps I tried with the Xdebug helper. Note: I already set breakpoints in Netbeans.

1. Navigate to the page I want to debug.
2. Turn on Debug in Xdebug helper.
3. Reload page.

Here is the screenshot showing that the debugger appeared to start but suspended and stopped functioning I think. [image]

So, I am looking for a bit of guidance and support figuring out if I may be using the tool wrong or if there is a better way to use it. Is there a way to activate it for a specific page and keep it running to debug ajax requests to php on the same page/project?

**System Info**

- Windows 10
- Wamp with PHP 5.6
- Chrome, newest version
- Using Moodle as a base and customing it.
- Netbeans 8.1

**Edit**

Here is my php.ini information.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="C:/WampDeveloper/Temp/xdebug"
```

Comment: Are you launching the site in debug mode? Or expecting it to be able to satrt debugging at some point in the middle of the site

Comment: If I launch the site in debug mode from Netbeans by using the Debug Project button I then have to navigate through the site to the page I want to debug which takes way too long with the debugger on.                                                With the Xdebug helper it was my understanding that you could start debugging from a specific page and navigate through the site from then on.

Comment: Ah maybe, I have never used the helper

Comment: Just read a little on helper. I dont think that is what helper is for.

Comment: Note: There is also a NetBeans 8.2 yo umight want to move to as well

Comment: Well, is there a way to avoid having to load the index page and navigate to the page I actually want to debug? Moodle on Wamp Windows is super slow and with the debugger on can take 2-3 minutes to get the to the page.

Comment: Then there are other things wrong with your system/config/etc

Comment: Just to be clear, normal websites load at normal speeds in WAMP. Moodle has a lot going on in the background and normally takes 15.24s to load the main page. With Netbeans Debugger on it takes 1.1 min to load just the home page, let alone navigate 5 pages deep to test. I checked computer performance and CPU draw is at 20% and memory is in the 70% range. Any ideas how I can optimize or increase the performance of Netbeans Debugging with XDebug? Also, am I using it incorrectly?